# Duplicate process without fork

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, ps

In linux embedded system I can see in `ps` 2 processes of the same binary(pid1=X, pid2=Y) those processes don't have threads(`/proc/X/task` and `/proc/Y/task` don't exist)

When I look on `/proc/Y/status` I can see that the parent pid(PPID) is X.

I looking on the binary file in Ida,that dynamic binary ,and do not see `fork` function in import table.

When I change the some instructions with PTRACE of pid X or pid Y that influence on the another pid, so that seem they share the same code area

If Y was thread of X I supposed to see it in `/proc/X/task` and not in `ps` without show threads flags.

Which function can duplicate process that share the same code area but of `fork` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Which function can duplicate process that share the same code area?

From what I know I can list syscalls:

- `fork`
- `vfork` - `fork` with some restrictions and faster
- `clone` - `fork` but linux-specific fine-tuning everything
- `clone3` - newer version of `clone()`
- `clone2` - `clone` that is IA-64 specific and only available on IA-64

Comment: are all those functions share import table and code area?

Comment: So did you read the documentation of these function and is there something unclear to you? The _functions_ do not have an import table, I guess you mean to ask if _processes created by those system calls_ share import table and code area.

Comment: yes,I mean  if processes created by those system calls share import table and code area